# parameter values only being sent to certain columns in google sheet?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have a web app form with text fields and dropdowns. I am trying to pass certain selections over to a google sheet. I want to bring (in this order): landowner, comments, date, land agent, parcel ID to the corresponding columns in google sheet (columns A-E).

[image]

When I press submit, everything but the landowner dropdown sends to the sheet:

[image]

Here's the DoPost and addrecord status I have:

```
function doPost(e) {
  // Check if the 'e' parameter is defined and contains the expected properties
  if (e && e.parameter) {
    var landowner = e.parameter.landowner ? e.parameter.landowner.toString() : '';
    var substation = e.parameter.substation ? e.parameter.substation.toString() : '';
    var comment = e.parameter.comment ? e.parameter.comment.toString() : '';
    var status = e.parameter.status ? e.parameter.status.toString() : '';
    var supervisor = e.parameter.supervisor ? e.parameter.supervisor.toString() : '';
    var date = e.parameter.date ? e.parameter.date : '';
    var parcelId = e.parameter.parcelId ? e.parameter.parcelId.toString() : ''; // Retrieve parcel ID parameter

    addRecord(landowner, comment, date, supervisor, parcelId); // Pass parcelId to addRecord
    addToStatuses(landowner, status, date, supervisor, parcelId); // Pass parcelId to addToStatuses
    removeDuplicateStatuses();

    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
    var subs = getDistinctSubstations();
    htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
    htmlOutput.subs = subs;

    return htmlOutput.evaluate();
  } else {
    // If 'e' parameter is not defined or doesn't contain expected properties, return an error message
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: Invalid request parameters");
  }
}
```

__

```
// Function to add a record to the Comments sheet
function addRecord(landowner, comment, date, supervisor, parcelId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Comments");
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
  dataSheet.appendRow([landowner, comment, formattedDate, supervisor, parcelId]); // Include landowner in column A
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm missing here?

EDIT: WHOLE SCRIPT CODE.GS

```
// Function to remove duplicate statuses
function removeDuplicateStatuses() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  var dataRange = statusSheet.getRange(3, 1, statusSheet.getLastRow() - 2, statusSheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = dataRange.getValues();

  // Create an object to store unique rows
  var uniqueRows = {};
  var uniqueData = [];

  // Iterate through the rows and store unique rows in the object
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    var key = row.join(",");
    uniqueRows[key] = row;
  }

  // Extract unique rows from the object
  for (var key in uniqueRows) {
    uniqueData.push(uniqueRows[key]);
  }

  // Clear the existing data from row 3 to the last row and write back the uniqueData
  statusSheet.getRange(3, 1, statusSheet.getLastRow() - 2, statusSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();
  if (uniqueData.length > 0) {
    statusSheet.getRange(3, 1, uniqueData.length, uniqueData[0].length).setValues(uniqueData);
  }
}

function doPost(e) {
  // Check if the 'e' parameter is defined and contains the expected properties
  if (e && e.parameter) {
    var landowner = e.parameter.landowner ? e.parameter.landowner.toString() : '';
    var substation = e.parameter.substation ? e.parameter.substation.toString() : '';
    var comment = e.parameter.comment ? e.parameter.comment.toString() : '';
    var status = e.parameter.status ? e.parameter.status.toString() : '';
    var supervisor = e.parameter.supervisor ? e.parameter.supervisor.toString() : '';
    var date = e.parameter.date ? e.parameter.date : '';
    var parcelId = e.parameter.parcelId ? e.parameter.parcelId.toString() : ''; // Retrieve parcel ID parameter

    addRecord(landowner, comment, date, supervisor, parcelId); // Pass parcelId to addRecord
    addToStatuses(landowner, status, date, supervisor, parcelId); // Pass parcelId to addToStatuses
    removeDuplicateStatuses();

    var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
    var subs = getDistinctSubstations();
    htmlOutput.message = 'Record Added';
    htmlOutput.subs = subs;

    return htmlOutput.evaluate();
  } else {
    // If 'e' parameter is not defined or doesn't contain expected properties, return an error message
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Error: Invalid request parameters");
  }
}


// Function to serve the initial HTML page
function doGet(e) {
  var htmlOutput = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('DependentSelect');
  var subs = getDistinctSubstations();
  htmlOutput.message = '';
  htmlOutput.subs = subs;
  htmlOutput.url = getUrl();
  return htmlOutput.evaluate();
}

// Function to get status options for a specific landowner
function getStatusOptions(landowner) {
  var maxStatus = getMaxStatusForLandowner(landowner);
  var options = ["", "Passed to Agent", "Outreach", "Negotiating", "Pledged", "Signed", "Denied"];
  var dropdownHTML = options.map(option => {
    if (option === maxStatus) {
      return `<option value="${option}" selected>${option}</option>`;
    } else {
      return `<option value="${option}">${option}</option>`;
    }
  }).join("");

  return dropdownHTML;
}

// Function to get landowner information
function getLandownerInfo(landowner) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var commentsSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Comments");
  var headers = rawDataSheet.getRange(2, 1, 1, rawDataSheet.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  var lastRow = rawDataSheet.getLastRow();
  var dataRange = rawDataSheet.getRange(3, 1, lastRow - 1, rawDataSheet.getLastColumn());
  var values = dataRange.getValues();
  var landownerInfo = "";
  var maxComment = "N/A";
  var maxCommentDate = "N/A";

  var commentsDataRange = commentsSheet.getRange(2, 1, commentsSheet.getLastRow() - 1, commentsSheet.getLastColumn());

  var commentsValues = commentsDataRange.getValues();

  for (var k = commentsValues.length - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    if (commentsValues[k][0] == landowner && commentsValues[k][1]) {
      maxCommentDate = Utilities.formatDate(commentsValues[k][2], Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
      maxComment = commentsValues[k][1];
      break;
    }
  }

  if (maxComment !== "N/A") {
    landownerInfo += "Comments: [" + maxCommentDate + "] " + maxComment + "\n\n";
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][3] == landowner) {
      var rowData = values[i];

      for (var j = 0; j < headers.length; j++) {
        if ([0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10, 20].indexOf(j) !== -1) {
          landownerInfo += headers[j] + ": " + rowData[j] + "\n";
        }
      }
      break;
    }
  }

  return landownerInfo;
}

// Function to get parcel IDs by landowner
function getParcelIdsByLandowner(landowner) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var landownerColumn = rawDataSheet.getRange('D3:D' + rawDataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var parcelIdColumn = rawDataSheet.getRange('U3:U' + rawDataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat();
  var matchingParcelIds = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < landownerColumn.length; i++) {
    if (landownerColumn[i] === landowner) {
      matchingParcelIds.push(parcelIdColumn[i]);
    }
  }

  return matchingParcelIds;
}

// Function to get distinct substations
function getDistinctSubstations() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var subs = rawDataSheet.getRange('E3:E' + rawDataSheet.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().filter((sub, index, self) => self.indexOf(sub) === index && sub !== "");
  return subs;
}

// Function to get parcels for a specific substation
function getParcels(substation) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var rawDataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Raw Data");
  var lastRow = rawDataSheet.getLastRow();
  var substationValues = rawDataSheet.getRange('E3:E' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var landownerValues = rawDataSheet.getRange('D3:D' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var filteredLandowners = [];
  var uniqueLandowners = new Set();

  for (var i = 0; i < substationValues.length; i++) {
    if (substationValues[i] === substation && landownerValues[i]) {
      uniqueLandowners.add(landownerValues[i]);
    }
  }

  filteredLandowners = Array.from(uniqueLandowners);

  return filteredLandowners;
}

// Function to get the maximum status for a specific landowner
function getMaxStatusForLandowner(landowner) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  var lastRow = statusSheet.getLastRow();
  var landownerValues = statusSheet.getRange('A4:A' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var statusValues = statusSheet.getRange('B4:B' + lastRow).getValues().flat();
  var maxStatus = "";

  for (var i = landownerValues.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (landownerValues[i] == landowner && statusValues[i]) {
      maxStatus = statusValues[i];
      break;
    }
  }

  return maxStatus;
}

// Function to add a record to the Comments sheet
function addRecord(landowner, comment, date, supervisor, parcelId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Comments");
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy HH:mm");
  dataSheet.appendRow([landowner, comment, formattedDate, supervisor, parcelId]); // Include landowner in column A
}

// Function to add a record to the Statuses sheet
function addToStatuses(landowner, status, date, supervisor, parcelId) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var statusSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Statuses");
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(date), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "MM/dd/yy");
  statusSheet.appendRow([landowner, status, formattedDate, supervisor, parcelId]); // Include landowner in column A
}

// Function to get the URL of the web app
function getUrl() {
  var url = ScriptApp.getService().getUrl();
  return url;
}
```

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <base target="_top">
  <title>Comment Submission Form</title>
  <style>
    /* Your CSS styles here */
    body {
      font-size: 15px;
      background-color: #f0f8ff;
      font-family: Arial, sans-serif; /* Light blue background color */
    }
    .container {
      width: 50%;
      margin: 0 auto; /* Center the container horizontally */
      text-align: center; /* Center the content inside the container */
      padding-top: 20px; /* Add space at the top */
    }
    h1 {
      margin-top: 20px; /* Add space between header image and header text */
      font-size: 20px;
    }
    select {
      width: 50%; /* Set the width of dropdown menus to fill the container */
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for dropdown values */
      text-align-last: center; /* Align dropdown selections in the middle */
    }
    /* Additional styling to center-align dropdown selections */
    option {
      text-align: center;
    }
    textarea {
      height: 100px;
      width: 250px;
      font-size: 12px;
      width: 100%; /* Set font size for textarea */
    }
    input[type="submit"] {
      font-size: 12px; /* Set font size for submit button */
    }
    .submit-message {
      color: red;
      font-size: 12px;
    }
    .landowner-info {
      float: center;
      margin-top: 20px;
      padding: 10px;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-radius: 5px;
      background-color: #f9f9f9;
      width: 100%; /* Extend size of landowner info box */
    }
  </style>
  <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
  <script>
    function updateParcelInfo(parcel) {
      updateParcelIds(parcel);
      updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcel);
      getLandownerInfo(parcel);
    }

    function updateParcelInfo(landowner) {
      // Trigger search in "Raw Data" worksheet for landowner value
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcelIds) {
        var parcelIdDropdown = document.getElementById("parcelId");
        parcelIdDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        parcelIdDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Populate Parcel ID dropdown with matching rows from columns U3:U
        parcelIds.forEach(function(parcelId) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parcelId;
          option.text = parcelId;
          parcelIdDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getParcelIdsByLandowner(landowner); // Call server function to get matching parcel IDs
    }

    function getLandownerInfo(parcel) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(landownerInfo) {
        var landownerInfoArray = landownerInfo.split(" (Phone: ");
        document.getElementById("landowner-info-content").innerText = landownerInfoArray[0];
        document.getElementById("phone-info-content").innerText = "Phone: " + landownerInfoArray[1].slice(0, -1); // Remove the closing parenthesis
      }).getLandownerInfo(parcel);
    }

    function getParcels(substation) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(parcels) {
        var parcelDropdown = document.getElementById("parcel");
        parcelDropdown.innerHTML = "";
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = "";
        option.text = "";
        parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Sort the parcel options alphabetically
        parcels.sort().forEach(function(parcel) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = parcel;
          option.text = parcel;
          parcelDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });

        // Update max status immediately after selecting parcel
        var selectedParcel = parcelDropdown.value;
        updateParcelInfo(selectedParcel);
      }).getParcels(substation);
    }

    function updateMaxStatusForParcel(parcel) {
      google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(maxStatus) {
        var statusDropdown = document.getElementById("status");
        statusDropdown.innerHTML = ""; // Clear previous options
        var option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = ""; // Set value to empty string
        option.text = ""; // Set text to empty string
        statusDropdown.appendChild(option);

        // Define status options
        var options = ["","Passed to Agent", "Outreach", "Negotiating", "Pledged", "Signed","Denied"];

        // Sort the status options alphabetically
        options.sort().forEach(function(status) {
          var option = document.createElement("option");
          option.value = status;
          option.text = status;
          if (status === maxStatus) {
            option.selected = true; // Select the option if it matches the max status
          }
          statusDropdown.appendChild(option);
        });
      }).getMaxStatusForParcel(parcel);
    }

    function validateForm() {
      var parcel = document.getElementById("parcel").value;
      var substation = document.getElementById("substation").value;
      var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;
      var status = document.getElementById("status").value; // Get status value

      if (!parcel || !substation || !comment || !status) {
        document.getElementById("submit-message").innerText = "All fields are required.";
        return false; // Prevent form submission
      }

      // Disable form submit button to prevent resubmission
      document.getElementById("submit-button").disabled = true;

      return true; // Allow form submission
    }

    // Reload the page after form submission to prevent resubmission popup
    window.onload = function() {
      if (window.history.replaceState) {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
      }
    };

    // Prevent form resubmission popup on page reload
    if (window.history.replaceState) {
      window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function () {
        window.history.replaceState(null, null, window.location.href);
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/16QsZja.png" alt="Header Image" style="width: 100%; max-width: 200px;">

    <h1>Comment/Status Submission Form</h1>

    <form method="post" action="<?= getUrl() ?>" onsubmit="return validateForm()">
      <label>Land Agent</label><br>
      <select name="supervisor" id="supervisor">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Dan">Dan</option>
        <option value="Ian">Ian</option>
        <option value="Parker">Parker</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Substation</label><br>
      <select name="substation" id="substation" onchange="getParcels(this.value)">
        <option value=""></option>
        <? var subs = getDistinctSubstations(); ?>
        <? subs.sort().forEach(function(sub) { ?>
          <option value="<?= sub ?>"><?= sub ?></option>
        <? }); ?>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Landowner</label><br>
      <select name="parcel" id="parcel" onchange="updateParcelInfo(this.value)">
        <!-- Parcel dropdown will be populated dynamically -->
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Parcel ID</label><br>
      <select name="parcelId" id="parcelId">
        <!-- Parcel ID dropdown will be populated dynamically -->
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Status</label><br>
      <select name="status" id="status">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="Passed to Agent">Passed to Agent</option>
        <option value="Outreach">Outreach</option>
        <option value="Negotiating">Negotiating</option>
        <option value="Pledged">Pledged</option>
        <option value="Signed">Signed</option>
        <option value="Denied">Denied</option>
      </select><br><br>

      <label>Date</label><br>
      <input type="text" name="date" id="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY"><br><br>

      <label>Comment</label><br>
      <textarea name="comment" id="comment"></textarea><br><br>

      <input type="submit" name="submitButton" id="submit-button" value="Submit" />
      <span id="submit-message" class="submit-message"></span>
    </form>

    <div class="landowner-info">
      <h2>Landowner Info</h2>
      <p id="landowner-info-content">Loading...</p>
      <p id="phone-info-content"></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What pieces of data are you missing?

Comment: You may not be able to pass a date from html to a server. Try passing it as a string.